# ¿Cómo ejecutar comando grep en Linux excluyendo archivos en subcarpetas específicas?

Tags: linux, grep

Tengo ciertos archivos, pongamos por ejemplo **archivo1.php** y **archivo2.php**, que están siempre dentro de la misma ruta relativa: `alfa/beta/`. Y esta estructura de subcarpetas (`alfa/beta/`) aparece en distintos lugares dentro de mi servidor. Como se ve en el siguiente árbol de carpetas, esa misma ruta relativa aparece en 3 lugares distintos: dentro de `/carpeta1/`, dentro de `/carpeta2/subcarpeta1/` y dentro de `/carpeta3/subcarpeta2/subcarpeta3/`:

```
/carpeta1/
    /alfa/
        /beta/
            archivo1.php
            archivo2.php
        archivo3.php
     /beta/
        archivo2.php
/carpeta2/
    archivo4.php
    /subcarpeta1/
        /alfa/
            /beta/
                archivo1.php
                archivo2.php
                archivo5.php
/carpeta3/
     /subcarpeta2/
        archivo6.php
        /subcarpeta3/
            /alfa/
                /beta/
                    archivo1.php
                    archivo2.php
                archivo7.php
                archivo1.php
```

**¿QUÉ QUIERO HACER?**

Quiero encontrar una cadena específica, digamos **hola**, en todos los archivos del servidor, pero excluyendo los archivos de mi estructura conocida; es decir, omitiendo siempre estos archivos: alfa/beta/archivo1.php y alfa/beta/archivo2.php.

**¿QUÉ ES LO QUE HE INTENTADO? (sin éxito)**

1. `grep -ril "hola" / --exclude="*{alfa/beta/archivo1.php, alfa/beta/archivo2.php}"`
2. `grep -ril "hola" / --exclude="alfa/beta/archivo1.php" --exclude="alfa/beta/archivo2.php"`

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: Intenta con `--exclude="*/alfa/beta/{archivo1.php, archivo2.php}"` a ver si funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con GNU grep no se puede, cuando la búsqueda es recursiva la opción `exclude` usa el nombre base y no la ruta completa.

Puedes conseguirlo con `find`:

```
find . ! -path *alfa/beta/archivo[12].php -type f -exec grep hola {} +
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Nada más para que quede como nota: yo logré obtener justo el resultado que tu encuentras en una línea, pero yo en 30-50 líneas más o menos. Primero hacía un find, guardaba los archivos en un array, luego iteraba sobre ese array y comparaba sus rutas con rutas de otro array whitelist... El caso es que anidaba bucles (3 en total), y mi script se tardaba unos 6 minutos en terminar. Me estoy metiendo con la consola Linux ya en serio desde no hace mucho (vengo de Windows), y me parece una herramienta simplemente GENIAL.